# Как закрыть стороннее приложение/ окно стороннего приложения mac objective-c

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, mac

Я открываю файлы из своей аппы, текст, фото, что угодно. И мне нужно закрывать их так же из моей аппы. Как это сделать, при активированном SandBox?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Сделать этого с включенным SandBox нельзя, но можно отправить просьбу аппе, что бы та закрылась, как это сделать написанно [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5291815/quitting-other-applications-in-cocoa). Да, аппа может вас проигнорировать и не закрыться:)

С выключенным SandBox просто вызовите [terminate в NSRunningApplication](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/AppKit/Reference/NSRunningApplication_Class/)
`NSRunningApplication` вы можете получить вот так:

```
[NSRunningApplication runningApplicationsWithBundleIdentifier:identifier];  
[NSRunningApplication runningApplicationWithProcessIdentifier:pid];
```

Массив всех запущенных апп можете получить из [NSWorkspace](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSWorkspace_Class/)